# Mobile data is not working. Android Lollipop on Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-5

I have flashed my nexus 5 with the last version of android Lollipop hammerhead(LRX21O).
The mobile data is not working, I can connect through WIFI to internet but there is no LTE/3g connectivity.

For call and SMS there is any problem. I have already configured the APS settings correctly.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with my Nexus 4. Wifi is fine, as is SMS and phone calls. Mobile data is completely dead.

Comment: when did you flash your nexus 4 and with which image?

Comment: yesterday, with the Lollipop factory image for Nexus 4 (LRX21T). Going to roll back to KitKat today and hope that the changes to the radio aren't permanent.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem on my Nexus 5 with Lollipop (3G not working, but 2G is working).

Comment: I have tried with LRX21O and LRX21T...and nothing

Comment: same issue with my nexus :( i hve tried to set network provider manually and select automatically .. bt same not able to connect mobile data :(

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question. android.stackexchange.com is probably a better place for device questions like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using Android, not programming.

Answer (score 7):

The Data "Cellular Data" option has moved from `Settings->More->Cellular networks->` to `Settings-> Data Usage`.

So enable "Cellular Data" option that's it. issue resolved.

Comment: That was the first thing that I did...

Answer (score 4):

Its working in my nexus 5 .. 
(1)First i hve selected network provider manually.
(2)From cellular network first i selected 2g ,and then 3gLTE
(3)Reboot(switched off and on) my device.Now Mobile data is connecting

[image]

Comment: I have tried it but still disconnected.

Comment: I read that the QFE1100 chip has trouble maintaining LTE connections when the signal gets weak. Switching to 3G only solved the dropped connections for me.
Settings -> More -> Mobile networks -> Preferred network tupe "3G"

Answer (score 4):

Finally .... I changed the MVNO-Type to any.
But Lollipop gave me wrong configuration for my mobile data. The error persist for the normal users who don`t know how to change APN configuration. In Addition, the APN configuration that provider suggest is not working neither.

If someone understand german..

http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/android5-lollipop-nexus5-besitzer/

Comment: That was exactly my problem - seems to be still a issue as i have a nexus 5 with a OTA 5.1 wich i rooted via Wugs Nexus Root Toolkit.

Comment: I have to say that the question is completely off-topic, but it also worked for me, thanks for posting it. Btw, I do not know if it's relevant but I live in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check your APN's again. I've had a similar problem, where sometimes I did hava mobile data and sometimes didn't. (On Nexus 5, sideloaded the OTA update)

Then I noticed I had multiple APN's, and the wrong APN was selected. I removed the not necessary APN's and I'm good now.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue on my Nexus 5, after I rooted it. Previous to rooting everything worked fine, but afterwards I had the following symptoms:
- Data connection was available and working fine after a reboot.
- If the data connection was turned off, it would not turn back when selected. It only got back working either by rebooting, or occasionally after some time (like 1, 2 hours).

I had tried to flash the radio, but mistakenly it was the Developer Preview (LPX13D) version. Be aware that this version of the radio is buggy, and after rooting presents these issues with the data connection not being always available. Flashing the final lollipop radio version (LRX21O) worked like a charm, and the radio data connection came back to life.

Hope this helps someone in need :)

Answer (score 1):

The APN settings are probably not updated during the System Update. I fixed mine by going to :-

```
>> Settings 
>> Data Usage 
>> Then selecting more icon":" on  the right top corner next to the search icon 
>> Select Cellular Network Settings 
>> Select Access Point Names and 
>> then Select the APN which was selected before the System Update.
```

This should solve the issue.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Change APN in settings AND change it in Hangouts.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd update an answer on here as I've been scratching my head for 2 days. I'm on 3 Mobile UK and had the same issue. I amended all settings and updated the APN as stated on the 3 website but nothing worked. Then suddenly I woke up this morning and it was working.

Not really a great answer but maybe it was something to do with a network update related to Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Set your carrier data to 1X or 2g to get a limited connection. WiFi might also work but I didn't try. Update your PRL and profile. Set carrier data preference back to whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug with the Nexus 5 for a large amount of customers.
As you guys mentioned it prevents owners of Nexus 5 to receive calls, sms's or make calls for an unknown or unidentified issue.

My research suggests that there is no solution which has been published and I have not found any evidence that this issue is or was addressed by Google or LG yet.
Hopefully it will soon as I have been using my "phone" as a browser for the last 2 months or so.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once. I was using mobile data from my balance and my balance went below zero. I switched off mobile data and put up a data plan. But when i switched mobile data back on, it just wont work. I then filled in some balance to get it above zero and then my mobile data started working just fine. Shared this cuz i thought it might be the case with someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create your APN Access Point Names manually. (if it's not detected automatically)

Usually your internet provider provides you the instruction to how to create that.
For instance my internet provider has an instruction page. 
https://www.ptel.com/support/phonesettings

Yours should be similar with different values.